# Django saving json value to database/model

Tags: python, json, django

Im new to django and im trying to save **json to database**. The problem is that im able to get data the data in my views but not sure **how to save it in database**. Im trying to save the **comments**

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    title=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    comments=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

serializer.py

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source="title.id", read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(source="title.title", read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('id','title','comments')


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','description','pub_date')
```

Please help me saving the data from views to database

view.py

```
def add_comments(request):
    if 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']:
        print 'hi'
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        comment = data.get('comment', None)
        id = data.get('id', None)
        title = data.get('title', None) 
        ....................# not sure how to save to database
       pass
```

Thanks in advance........Please let me know if there is any better way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly then
Your view should be something like.

```
def add_comments(request):
    if 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']:
        print 'hi'
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        comment = data.get('comment')
        id = data.get('id')
        title = data.get('title') 
        
        post = Post.objects.get(id = id)
        com = Comment()
        com. comments = comment
        com.title = post
        com.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...Yes this is what is required.........Is there a better way of storing data...instead of individually adding data......?

Comment: (de)serializations in django

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Postgres, you can store json with `JSONField` ([read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)), but if not, you need parse json to string and save with `CharField`/`TextField` using `json.dumps(data)`. To recovery data, use json string to dict with `json.loads(json_string)`

Remember to import json lib: `import json`

## Update 2023

Based on @Jarad comment,

> JSONField is supported on MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite (with the JSON1 extension enabled).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: *JSONField is supported on MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite (with the JSON1 extension enabled).* [Django 4.2 Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming a model of:

```
class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  phone_number = models.CharField()
```

Sending json of {"name":"Test User", "phone_number":"123-456-7890"}

In the view you could do the following to save it to the database.

```
def SaveUser(request):
  body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
  body = json.loads(body_unicode)
  u = User(**body)
  u.save()
  return JsonResponse({"result": "OK"})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store the intact JSON, try using the django-jsonfield project: https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield

Answer (score 0):

according to Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) you can use :

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

then create with this :

```
Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={
     'breed': 'labrador',
     'owner': {
         'name': 'Bob',
         'other_pets': [{
             'name': 'Fishy',
         }],
     },
})
```